# Domino 8.5.3 regression with Date time

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

We have recently been testing 8.5.3 and have identified a new issue with how date time values are rendered on xpages.

**Issue:**

Any datetime fields containing just the time value (e.g., 11:00 AM) when shown in an editable field on xpages gets converted to a different value due to TZ.

If the server is in India (GMT + 5.30) it adds 5.5 hrs and shows 11:00 AM as 04:30 PM. Basically, it assumes all times as GMT unless specified. 
This new value also gets saved in the document when saved (so it stores it as 04/08/2012 04:30:00 PM ZE5B) as a result corrupting the original value.

This did not use to happen in 8.5.2 or before and has affected several of our apps.

Has anybody seen this before and can suggest a fix or workaround. 
Would appreciate any help.

Comment: You should open a PMR if you consider if an application which worked pre-8.5.3, doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Yes, open a pmr ( see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699074/inconsistent-times-being-stored-in-xpages/10757207#10757207 which I think is the same issue) -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LO67745: XPAGES: CORRECT TIME DOESN'T SHOW ON DATE TIME PICKER
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1LO67745

8.5.3 FP3 has the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the application properties? You can specify what timezone to use. Server or browser. When you open a PMR post the PMR number here.

Comment: Yes did not help. The application worked earlier in 852, so I am sure something changed. I don't have access to post a PMR would help if someone can report this.