# Inconsistent Times being stored in XPages

Tags: datetime, xpages

If I have an XPage with a Time field on it:

```
<xp:inputText id="inputText2" value="#{document1.Time}"
    defaultValue="#{javascript:@Now()}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="time"
            ignoreUserTimeZone="false"
            timeStyle="full">
        </xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:inputText>
```

My server is set to UK time, when I save the document and then view it again the time will have moved on by one hour.

In my xsp.properties file I have:

```
xsp.user.timezone=true
xsp.user.timezone.roundtrip=true
```

Is this a bug or me not having configured my server correctly?

Comment: Have you tried populating it a different way?  Maybe rather then @Now() you create a NotesDateTime object?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas guys. I've tried every combination of settings that I can think of with no luck.

Comment: @Frantisek - yes some sort of time converter is necessary, otherwise just the date will be displayed which is not what I'm after in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug and regression (the above works in 852). IBM is working on a fix. More on that later, but in the meantime call this in with Support and when a hotfix becomes available we'll get that to you.

Comment: When calling IBM Support reference the following SPR HOKA8RZ5KL to speed things along.

Answer (score 2):

I have Mark Myers to thank for this answer.

It seems that the issue is time zone related, but odd. The server is set to observe daylight savings, if we turn this off then the code works as expected. The problem then is that "classic" Domino apps no longer work. So, in my mind, I consider this a bug. But at least for now we have a solution.

Thanks for the assistance.

Matt

Comment: Does it mean, that native Domino converts timezone, and xsp engine does it again?

Comment: This bug can be reproduced regardless of timezones on time only input fields. In read mode these fields will display the original time plus an extra hour. If you then edit and save, that extra hour will be saved and thus corrupting your data.

Answer (score 1):

could this be an issue with daylight savings being set somewhere?

Comment: I guess the question would be where "somewhere" might be.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same Issue, After Install FixPack3 in lotus notes client 8.5.3 then this has been resolved

Thanks

Richard Arun kumar.A